# get a value from key value pair list in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display a specific value from key value list..
 here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0 )
{ 
    foreach($_POST as $paramName => $paramValue) {
            echo "<br/>" . $paramName . " = " . $paramValue;
    }
}
```

ouput

```
ORDERID = ORDS3700373
TXNAMOUNT = 200.00
CURRENCY = INR
TXNID = 32221284
BANKTXNID = 475815
STATUS = TXN_SUCCESS
RESPCODE = 01
RESPMSG = Txn Successful.
TXNDATE = 2017-01-10 18:13:25.0
GATEWAYNAME = WALLET
BANKNAME = 
PAYMENTMODE = PPI
CHECKSUMHASH =
```

here I want to display only ORDERID and TXNID.. How do I get that value?

Comment: `$_POST['ORDERID']` and `$_POST['TXNID']`?

Comment: while giving like this it shows the duplicated values..

Comment: Oh don't put it in a loop. Just literally access the `value` at the `key`. `$_POST` is nothing more then a global array you do not need the `foreach` if you just want those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comments to an answer.

You do not need to loop post it is just a `global array`. You can access the `value`s at any of the `key`s like any associative array because that is what it is. Likewise these `value` can be used like any other

```
if(isset($_POST['ORDERID'])){
    $orderid = $_POST['ORDERID'];
}

if(isset($_POST['TXNID'])){
    $txnid = $_POST['TXNID'];    
}

// Should use htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() here 
// but didn't want to confuse OP. It is for security.
echo "ORDERID is: " . $orderid . " and TXNID is: " . $txnid;
```

*A note for security never trust user input and sanitize all `$_POST` variables before echoing or persisting. There are far better article out on the internet than I can summarize here.*

Answer (score 2):

You can easily access post values by it's field name instead of looping through all post elements. Simply access that elements directly as below:

```
if(isset($_POST['ORDERID'])) {
    echo 'ORDERID = '.$_POST['ORDERID'];
}
if(isset($_POST['TXNID'])) {
    echo 'TXNID= '.$_POST['TXNID'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition in the loop like this

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0 )
{ 
    foreach($_POST as $paramName => $paramValue) {
       if($paramName == 'ORDERID' || $paramName == 'TXNID')
            echo "<br/>" . $paramName . " = " . $paramValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a performance hit. Why loop through the whole array if you are only looking for a set of well-known properties?

Answer (score 0):

add an if like

```
if($paramName == "ORDERID" || $paramName == "TXNID") {
```

after foreach, remeber to close it after echo statement line

Comment: how do I store each value to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate a trivial task with a loop. 
Just drop the loop and echo the two values directly:

```
// Assuming the two values are expected to come in pair: 
if(isset($_POST['ORDERID']) && isset($_POST['TXNID'])) {
    echo "<br/>ORDERID = " . $_POST['ORDERID'];
    echo "<br/>TXNID = " . $_POST['TXNID'];
}
```

If you insist on having a loop, then you can go through the property names which you need

```
foreach(array('ORDERID', 'TXNID') as $paramName) {
    if(isset($_POST[$paramName])) {
        echo "<br/>" . $paramName . " = " . $_POST[$paramName];
    }
}
```